# Need a regex to match decimal numbers without leading 0s

Tags: php, mysql, regex

It should match 0.1, 1, .01, but not 01, 00.1, or anything with chars.

I'm trying to determine if a value should be quoted and escaped before being put into a mysql insert statement.  I have to watch out for some varchar keys that could be numeric with leading 0s that would be truncated if inserted as a number.

I'd also use a built in php or mysql function, if available.

EDIT: This one seems to cover all my bases:

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0\.[0-9]+|\.[0-9]+|0)$/
```

Comment: Have you tried to make the regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:^|\s|,)((?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))(?:$|\s|,)
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/kGYayNHItL).

Or

```
^((?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))$
```

if they appear each in a single line. See [here](http://rubular.com/r/Z4ZhRQ8OjP).

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
([1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?)|(0?\.\d+)
```

Comment: Wouldn't match `.01` ; a more complex regexp is required; maybe: `^(([1-9]\d*)?\.\d+|[1-9]\d*|0\.\d+)$`

Comment: This still matches the 1 and 0.1 in 01 and 00.1

Answer (score 1):

This would suit your examples:

```
preg_match('#^(?=[1-9]|0\.|\.\d)\d*(\.\d+)?$#', $num)
```

The `?=` assertion ensures that it either starts with `1-9` or `0.`, so any other leading zeros are excluded. You might want to limit the amount of decmals `\d+` can match though.